# Sorting function/variables in an object by name

Tags: javascript, organization, phpstorm

Are there any tools that can tidying up code and also sort the methods in my JavaScript objects by name for me? I use PHPStorm IDE so if there is a way to do this using that tool it would be best.

```
   Ext.regController
("dashboard", {
        goToShoppingCart:function() {
            Ext.dispatch({
               controller:"shoppingCart",
               action:"loadCart" 
            });
        },
        goToDashboard:function() {},
        goToContact:function() {}}
);
```

to

```
Ext.regController("dashboard", {
        goToContact:function() {},
        goToDashboard:function() {},
        goToShoppingCart:function() {
            Ext.dispatch({
               controller:"shoppingCart",
               action:"loadCart" 
            });
        }
    }
);
```

This is only for organization.

Thanks

Comment: Object properties have no order by definition of the specification. What difference do you think it makes?

Comment: @pimvdb It would just be for readability.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the source code? If so, I'm sorry, I missed that (I thought you wanted to do so at runtime).

Comment: @pimvdb No problem. I do mean formatting the source code.

Answer (score 2):

I asked on the jetbrains forum if it exists and a mod said no and suggest I put in a feature request.

I did that here
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-8438

If anyone else finds a tool that can do this I will accept their answer.

Edit - IntlliJ added this feature in 2017

https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/05/webstorm-2017-2-eap/#code-rearrangement

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you is generating javascript with PHP, you can do something like:

```
   $javascript_code = "var obj = {
   getB:function B(){},
   getA:function A(){},
   getC:function C(){},
}"; 
$obj_name = preg_match("/((?:var\s*)[^=]+)/",$javascript_code, $var_name);

preg_match_all("/(?<name>\w+):(?<value>.*(?:,|\s*))/", $javascript_code, $variables);
sort($variables["name"]);
sort($variables["value"]);

for($x = 0; $x < count($variables["name"]) / 2; $x++) {
    $variables["name"][$variables["name"][$x].':'] = $variables["value"][$x];
}
$outputcode = "{$var_name[1]} = { \r\n";

foreach($variables["name"] as $name => $value) {
    if(!is_numeric($name)) {
        $outputcode .= "{$name} {$value}\r\n";
    }
}

$outputcode .= "\r\n}";

echo $outputcode;
```

Output:

```
var obj  = { 
getA: function A(){},

getB: function B(){},

getC: function C(){},


}
```

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, but the only html/JS our backend serves is static and we want to keep it that way. Anything we need from the backend comes from an ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JStoolbox.

Using Sort enter `,`

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7353?pr=